# Primefaces checkbox client side value

Tags: java, checkbox, primefaces

I have a checkbox asking if someone is an adult. Then I have 2 inputs. The problem is how to, after changing the checkbox value, alter the required property of the inputs. 
I am updating the whole form, and it works. Is there a better way to do that? Second, is there a way to do it all on client side?

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="adultCheckbox" value="#{bean.adult}">
    <p:ajax update="@form"/>    
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:inputText id="property1" value="#{bean.property1}"
    required="#{bean.adult eq true }"/>
<p:inputText id="property2" value="#{bean.property2}"
    required="#{bean.adult eq true }"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it a little bit better:

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="adultCheckbox" value="#{bean.adult}">
    <p:ajax update="property1, property2"/>    
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

<p:inputText id="property1" value="#{bean.property1}"
    required="#{bean.adult}"/>
<p:inputText id="property2" value="#{bean.property2}"
    required="#{bean.adult}"/>
```

You could do something on client side customizing the Client Side Validation as described [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csvCustom.jsf). Buy I still believe is a good idea to do that through a Ajax Request.

Comment: wonder what makes this process? isnt it default setet to @this? Second i not need update also adultCheckbox, cause the bean not receiving new value?

Comment: It's partial submitting. To make it short, with process="@this" only the checkbox will be submitted when you change it, without it, you will send the whole form (including property1 and property2). If you really want to do that using client side, check the Custom Client Side Validation as I mentioned on the last edition of the post.

Comment: The **process** attribute of the p:ajax component has it's default value set to **@this**, so you'd better remove it. My bad!